# Rails migration not running to rename a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a migration to change the table name but when i do `rake db:migrate` the table name is not changed and I do not see any error in console as well

```
class RenameTemplatesTableToUserTemplates < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
    def up
      rename_table :templates, :user_templates
    end

    def down
      rename_table :job_templates, :templates
    end
end
```

I even tried the following

```
class RenameTemplatesTableToUserTemplates < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
    def self.up
      rename_table :templates, :user_templates
    end

    def self.down
      rename_table :job_templates, :templates
    end
end
```

And I also tried

```
class RenameTemplatesTableToUserTemplates < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
    def change
      rename_table :templates, :user_templates
    end
end
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

If your migration run does not output something :

`== 20170925112749 RenameTableTemplatesUserTemplates: migrating =========================
-- rename_table(:templates, :user_templates)
   -> 0.1690s
== 20170925112749 RenameTableTemplatesUserTemplates: migrated (0.1691s) ================`

and logs no errors, it could mean a migration with the same time-stamp has run already.
you can check it with 
 `RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake db:migrate:status` (dev)
In which case you should roll back this particular migration or update the time stamp on the new migration.

Also you need to edit files and associations (see [here](https://addstar34.github.io/rails-activerecord-rename-model-and-table/) )